# How do I migrate from TFS to VSO? Unable to enter VSO endpoint which I assume is the VSO URL

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I've tried adding the VSO endpoint which I assume is the VSO URL but getting an error. Where do I find the VSO endpoint details?

Comment: Hi, the process to end a VSO endpoint is exactly as how you would add a TFS end point in Visual Studio. Ensure that your have the 's' of https in the url. The port is not required for VSO urls. And the credentials are proper

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the very small doc? 
http://www.opshub.com/main/images/MigrationUtility/configuration.png